# Possible NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet requiring Json.NET v 4.5 bug?

Tags: json.net, nodatime

I found old posts related to NodaTime requiring Json.Net v4.5, but that was fixed. I seem to be seeing the same thing with NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet.

The simplest way to reproduce this error: By adding and removing NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet (via NugGet) to a VS project in my solution, I get runtime assembly binding/load errors for Json.Net v4.5 (I have v 6.x) installed. When I remove NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet, all is well.

NodaTime by itself is fine -- it is just when I add NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet the error occurs.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Some more information:

I've narrowed this down further, and have isolated the issue such that it only occurs when the WCF method is called from within the PowerShell runtime. NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet works just fine in the WCF-only tests.

On the call to 'ConfigureForNodaTime', the error is:

Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'll continue to look at this, but wanted to provide an update.

Additional information:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///S:/_Jp/DevProjCommon/__TEST/__TEST/bin/x64/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: S:\_Jp\DevProjCommon\__TEST\__TEST\bin\x64\Debug\TestApp.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///S:/_Jp/DevProjCommon/__TEST/__TEST/bin/x64/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

app.config (fyi):

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Jon, Matt:

When I opened the source, the NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet project settings refers to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.3\ref\Newtonsoft.Json.dll', v4.0.30319, 4.5.0.0, True

Perhaps when building the CS project files resolved to that path given these settings:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Portability)' == 'Desktop'">
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\jsonnet\Net35\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Portability)' == 'PCL'">
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\jsonnet\Portable\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

If I bypass the 'ConfigureForNodaTime' extension method, and try to add the NodaTime converters to the serializer instance in a helper method the same error occurs. So in specific terms, I cannot get past the addition of converters. I can't step into the helper method that adds the converters without hitting the assembly load exception.

I've also been able to reproduce this outside of PowerShell as well, in a console app that references my web api library and Json.Net serialization assembly.

I am going to add the source to my project (vs. this test project) and recompile to see if this fixes the issue.

Update:

When I load the "All" solution (source), and try to build I found the warning below. As an experiment, I changed the target (.net) framework to v4.5 from v3.5 client and the warning went away.

The primary reference "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework. NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet

Update:
While I do not yet have a smoking gun, I can confirm that ridding myself of Nuget dependency issues did not alleviate the problem (that one was on my suspicions). In an effort to find the bookends, I added the source for both Json.Net and NodaTime to my solution to gain greater control.

The successful workaround was changing the target framework on the NodaTime projects to .NET v4.5. v4.0 did not work, v4.5 did. That isn't a "fix" for NodaTime (which I do indeed love, btw) per se, since one of the objectives is to make it available to a broad range of applications that may not use the latest .NET framework version. But it is (I hope) a data point that may prove useful in diagnosing possible changes (if needed for others).

I'm under a fair amount of time pressure right now, but I will commit to eventually finding the smoking gun in my particular case just in case someone else may come across it in the future.

Warmest regards, Jp

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong without seeing the error message. The NuGet package only requires Json.NET >= 4.5.11, so I'd *expect* it to work. Can you reproduce in just a tiny console app?

Comment: Hi Jon, how are you sir!

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue in a console app, at least not yet.

This is a fairly sophisticated app (PowerShell binary module, WCF Client, etc.). I have narrowed down it a bit further: The exception occurs when executing the 'ConfigureForNodaTime' statement.

That is more specific than my original comment. :) If I comment out that statement, no errors occur.

Thank you!

-Jp

Comment: Please put all of that information into the question, along with the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

I can only reproduce this issue when targeting .Net 3.5, and using Json.Net 6.0.1 or greater.  In that case, the build output tells you the problem:

> The primary reference "NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4226afe0d9b296d1, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5".

NuGet adds a binding redirect to your config file, which solves the problem for .Net 4.0 and higher, but doesn't appear to work for .Net 3.5.

So if you need to target .Net 3.5, then use Json.Net 5.0.8.  If you can target .Net 4.0 or newer, then you can use the latest version of Json.Net.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Do you think there's a way to work around this?  I'm surprised the binding redirect doesn't work in .Net 3.5, but does work in 4.0 or 4.5.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand it yet. Is the problem that NuGet installs the latest version of Json.NET even though that's not appropriate for the project you're trying to work against?

Comment: In a .net 3.5 project, if you just install `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet` and let nuget pull down the dependencies then it grabs Json.net 4.5.11 and all is fine.  You can update all the way to Json.net 5.0.8 and it still works.  But if you just grab the latest version (6.0.1 or higher), it can't compile.  I'm not sure exactly why, but I think the solution is to build the NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet nuget package with both net35-Client and net40-Client versions, where the net35 version references json.net's net35 version at compile time.

Comment: Hi Jon and Matt, sorry I was unable to reply yesterday. I am building with v4.5 (Full). The assembly binding viewer output merely shows (my) assm as the calling assm. I'll post more tomorrow.